# How to parse JSON to nested struct in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, codable

I'm going to parse this JSON:

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "member": {
        "id": "3",
        "member_no": "1111",
        "username": "uname",
        "name": "name",
        "email": "user@name.com",
        "phone": "123 123",
        "point": "100",
        "expiry": "2019-09-22",
        "grade": {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Member"
        }
    }
}
```

I created this struct:

```
struct User: Codable {
    var status: Int?
    var member: Member?
    var msg: String?

    struct Member: Codable {
        var id: Int?
        var member_no: String?
        var username: String?
        var name: String?
        var email: String?
        var phone: String?
        var point: String?
        var expiry: String?
        var grade: Grade?

        struct Grade: Codable {
            var id: Int?
            var name: String?
        }
    }
}
```

And use this to decode:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let user = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: data)
```

But I got this error:

> The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

If the struct only one level, it is no problem:

```
struct User: Codable {
    var status: Int?
    var msg: String?
}
```

How to write a struct to match this JSON?

Comment: `id` is not an Int.

Comment: It can be  Int depends on the response. In swift we can take it whatever we want

Comment: @AdityaSharma No, it can't. Look at the JSON. It's a string. It doesn't magically become an Int just because you type the property as an Int.

Comment: oh yaa it is sorry

Comment: OK, changed to String, now is no problem

Comment: `let user = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: data)` Where is the catch? Where is the print of that error? Did you print only the localizedDescription? If so, print the full error instead. It should give useful infos...

Comment: In the future never `print(error.localizedDescription)` when parsing JSON, always `print(error)`.  It would have shown you the actual error *Expected to decode Int but found a string/data instead* along with the affected CodingKey rather than more generic and misleading *The data couldn’t be read...*

Comment: Replace ids type in `Grade ` to String and it'll work fine

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try as following, which seems to work fine for me.

First we need to create `CodingKeys` for our struct `User`

When working with codable, even though `Member` and `Grade` inside of member are nested each other. You should declare those structs, out of the User struct.

As you can see on the following Member and Grade should conform to `Codable`, while User conforms to `Decodable` in an extension and initializes with a decoder by using it as a container.

Also since in your json file you have `id` as `String` in both User and Grade but in your code you declared them as `Int` so I have also fixed them.

The code below implements structs and CodingKeys as I have mentioned above, try to approach as I did or try it by copying pasting it, and it should be fine:

User struct with CodingKeys:

```
struct User {
var status: Int?
var member: Member?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case status = "status"
    case member = "member"
}
}
```

Member and Grade structs:

```
struct Member: Codable {
var id: String?
var member_no: String?
var username: String?
var name: String?
var email: String?
var phone: String?
var point: String?
var expiry: String?
var grade: Grade?
}

struct Grade: Codable {
var id: String?
var name: String?
}
```

Extension for User to conform Codable:

```
extension User: Decodable {
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    self.status = try container.decode(Int?.self, forKey: .status)
    self.member = try container.decode(Member?.self, forKey: .member)
}
}
```

Now create a decoder and try to decode it as following:

```
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let user = try! decoder.decode(User.self, from: data)
```

I hope this helps and work fine for you

Answer (score 0):

xcode has probably thrown you an error, saying your struct doesn't conform to the decodable protocol, you didn't care about it :]

here is what your struct (model) should look like

```
struct User: Codable {
    let status: Int?
    let member: Member?
}
```

struct Member: Codable {
    let id, memberNo, username, name: String?
    let email, phone, point, expiry: String?
    let grade: Grade?

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case memberNo = "member_no"
    case username, name, email, phone, point, expiry, grade
}
```

}

struct Grade: Codable {
    let id, name: String?
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import Foundation

struct User: Codable {
    let status: Int
    let member: Member
}

struct Member: Codable {
    let id, memberNo, username, name: String
    let email, phone, point, expiry: String
    let grade: Grade

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case memberNo = "member_no"
        case username, name, email, phone, point, expiry, grade
    }
}

struct Grade: Codable {
    let id, name: String
}
```

Answer (score -1):

struct User: Codable {
var status: Int?
var member: Member?
var msg: String?

```
struct Member: Codable {
    var id: String?
    var member_no: String?
    var username: String?
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var phone: String?
    var point: String?
    var expiry: String?
    var grade: Grade?

    struct Grade: Codable {
        var id: String?
        var name: String?
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

You have strings in the ids and not integers:

```
struct User: Codable {
    var status: Int?
    var member: Member?

    struct Member: Codable {
        var id: String?
        var member_no: String?
        var username: String?
        var name: String?
        var email: String?
        var phone: String?
        var point: String?
        var expiry: String?
        var grade: Grade?

        struct Grade: Codable {
            var id: String?
            var name: String?
        }
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let user = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: data)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```